# Listbox: how to scroll many items, with columns, vertically?

Tags: delphi, listbox

Total Commander has Listbox which can scroll, in Thumbs mode, vertically, with N columns. If 100 items, then line 1 has N items, line 2 has N items,.... and scrollbar is vertical. I cannot do it in Delphi7. I added 100 items and set `Columns=4` but scroll is horizontal.

How to make it vertical?

Comment: A list view is absolutely the right control for this

Comment: If Total Commander's list supports "Thumbs" mode, it isn't a TListBox. It's a TListView, which is a standard Windows common control (the same thing used in the right pane of Windows Explorer).

Comment: @KenWhite: Technically, it is 'the same thing *previously* used in the right pane'...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: OK; I probably should have said "similar to the right pane of Explorer". What is it now, and since when? It still seems to be the underlying control used in the IShellWindow interfaces, AFAICT (at least on Win7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using the `TListView` instead of the `TListBox`. The list box is used for simpler things.

The `TListBox` does present only a horizontal scroll bar when `Columns > 0`, according to [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TListBox.Columns) (emphasis mine):

> Multi-column list boxes have a **horizontal** scroll bar that allows users
>   to view multiple columns as they wrap.

In addition, this is not a limitation of the VCL list box control. Indeed, according to [the MSDN article on the standard Windows List Box control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **LBS_MULTICOLUMN**
>
> Specifies a multi-column list box that is scrolled **horizontally**. The
>   list box automatically calculates the width of the columns, or an
>   application can set the width by using the LB_SETCOLUMNWIDTH message.
>   If a list box has the LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style, an application can set
>   the width when the list box sends the WM_MEASUREITEM message.
>
> A list box with the LBS_MULTICOLUMN style **cannot scroll vertically**—it
>   ignores any WM_VSCROLL messages it receives.

Comment: How TOtalCmd does it? New control for this isn't ok for app.

Comment: @RProgram: Are you sure Total Commander uses a standard Windows LISTBOX control?

Comment: Seems yes. It uses `TMyListbox` for panel (usual and thumb modes), `TMyCombobox` for drives, `TMyPanel` for panels.

Comment: @RProgram: And `TMyListbox` is based on `TCustomListBox`?